# Superscript and subscript axis labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I need an axis label in ggplot2 which reads "Assimilation (μmol CO2 m-2 s-1)" with the 2 of CO2 as subscript and the -2 and -1 as superscript.
Thanks.

Comment: Read `help("plotmath")`.

Answer (score 115):

You could try

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(uptake, data = CO2) +
   xlab(bquote('Assimilation ('*mu~ 'mol' ~CO[2]~ m^-2~s^-1*')'))
```

[image]