# how to add superscript into facet labels of facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, superscript, facet-wrap

I would like to add superscript into strip text of `facet_wrap`. First, I used `bquote` to assemble texts according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445452/superscript-and-subscript-axis-labels-in-ggplot2):

```
a <- bquote('2007, pop = 5.6 p' ~ m^-2)
b <- bquote('2007, pop = 2.8 p' ~ m^-2)
c <- bquote('2008, pop = 5.6 p' ~ m^-2)
d <- bquote('2009, pop = 5.6 p' ~ m^-2)
```

and then change names of levels and facet labels according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472980/ggplot-how-to-change-facet-labels),

```
levels(df21$trt)<-c(a,b,c,d)
```

but the facet labels did not change anything. Any help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The answer from the post could not solve my question, because my facet label is not math formula and facet_wrap_labeller seems to change facet label to math formula.

Comment: I doubt that language objects (such as those produced by bquote) will survive being stuck into factor label attributes. They will almost certainly be coerced to 'character' class.

Comment: I still don't know how to adapt `facet_wrap_labeller` for my situation. Would you please post a short answer? I will accepted it as the best answer. Thank you for advance!