# Superscripting in ggplot2 using plotmath

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, superscript, plotmath

I'm trying to get a superscript for units of my y-axis using plotmath expressions referenced in several posts. I've looked through threads on using [*expression*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445452/superscript-and-subscript-axis-labels-in-ggplot2) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202667/how-to-use-subscripts-in-ggplot2-legends-r), but it just isn't working for me. Here's what I have so far:

```
ggplot(data.frame, aes(Region, Zmar_sh)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + xlab("Region") +  
  ylab(expression(paste("eelgrass shoot density", " (shoots/", expression(m[2])))) +
  ggtitle(expression(paste(italic("Zostera marina")," shoot density in X Bay", sep = " ")))
```

The ggtitle expression works, but I'm still not getting my y axis to read "eelgrass shoot density (shoots/m2)" with the "2" as superscript. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need the second `expression()`. Also, `m[2]` gives a subscript. Use `m^2` for a superscript.

Here's an example with the built-in `mtcars` data frame:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab(expression(paste("eelgrass shoot density", " (shoots/", m^2,")")))
```

In fact, you don't even need to use `paste`. Instead you could do this:

```
ylab(expression(eelgrass~shoot~density~(shoots/m^2)))
```

where `~` is the "space" character. If you put actual spaces between the words (without using `~`), you'll get an error. However, for readability, you can also do this:

```
ylab(expression(eelgrass ~ shoot ~ density ~ (shoots/m^2)))
```

which is equivalent to the code above, because the spaces are ignored as long as the `~` is there.

Any of the `ylab` expressions above will give the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of this use of the ~. I knew it was something small that I was missing. And you were right about the superscript, of course. I am also working with subscripts in my code and wrote the incorrect term in my rush to post.