# How to include the math intersection operator into ggplot label

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot() + 
    labs(x = "Bla")
```

I want to change the "Bla" label from the previous code so that it displays this equation:

[image]

However, I don't know how to include the intersection operator. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @YacineHajji Sorry, this includes absolutely zero information about the intersection operator

Comment: The search criteria you need to help find many many good examples on SO: `plotmath`. Reading [`?plotmath`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html) gives you a lot of information, and you can use `parse`, `expression`, or `bquote` for various needs. Try `ggplot() + labs(x = expression(Delta * over(A * bgroup("(", E[M] * intersect() * E[E], ")"), A * bgroup("(", E[E], ")"))))`.

Comment: For starters, https://stackoverflow.com/q/35880053/3358272 has good examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `?plotmath` you could add an intersection operator via `intersect()`:

Note: Thx to @G.Grothendieck for teaching me that wrapping inside `expression()` is not needed.

```r
library(ggplot2)

#xlab <- expression(Delta~frac(A(E[M]~intersect()~E[E]), A(E[E])))

xlab <- Delta~frac(A(E[M]~intersect()~E[E]), A(E[E]))

ggplot() + 
  labs(x = xlab)
```

[image]

Comment: The `xlab<-` line could be shortened to `xlab <- Delta~frac(A(E[M]~intersect()~E[E]), A(E[E]))`

Comment: Thx @G.Grothendieck for teaching me this. Wasn't aware that wrapping inside `expression()` is not needed. Crazy. (:

Comment: It accepts formulas.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you should use the `latex2exp` package to write the legend directly in Latex, as follows:

```
library(latex2exp)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  labs(x = TeX(r'($\Delta \frac{A(E_M \cap E_E)}{A(E_E)}$)'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use unicode for symbols. For example `\u0394` for delta and `\u2229` for intersection.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + xlab(expression("\u0394"~frac(A(E[M]~"\u2229"~E[E]), A(E[E]))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>