# Superscript in axis labels in ggplot2 for ions

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to achieve superscript in an axis label within ggplot2, similiar to this question: [Superscript and subscript axis labels in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445452/superscript-and-subscript-axis-labels-in-ggplot2)

However, I will need to write something like this: Ca^**2+**. This seems not to work with this approach, even if I put the exponent in `{ }` with the `bquote` command. I tried to read through `help("plotmath")` but couldn't find an example for my case. I tried escaping the `+` with `\+` and `++` but was not successful.

Edit: I would like to not use any additional packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put the superscript as a literal, between quotes.

```
g <- ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + geom_boxplot()
g + xlab(bquote('Superscript as a literal' ~~ Ca^'2+'))
```

[image: ded an image.]

Comment: @stephanmg I guess so, yes. That depends on the amount of space you want between the text and the symbol.

Comment: I think I can accept this answer, I'm sorry I cannot accept multiple answers.

Answer (score 3):

Using the example you provided, this works

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(uptake, data = CO2) +
  xlab(bquote('Assimilation ('*mu~ 'mol' ~Ca^{"2+"} ~ m^-2~s^-1*')'))
```

[image]

Comment: Shoot! I did not think of using quotation marks, thanks @matushiq.

Answer (score 2):

using the `ggtext` package makes this straight forward.
Code shamelessly adapted from Claus Wilke's example in the readme. https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)
library(glue)

data <- tibble(
  atom = "Ca",
  charge = "2+",
  value = -0.5
)

data %>% mutate(
  color = "#009E73",
  name = glue("<i style='color:{color}'>{atom}</i><b><sup>{charge}</sup></b>"),
  name = fct_reorder(name, value)
)  %>%
  ggplot(aes(value, name, fill = color)) + 
  geom_col(alpha = 0.5) + 
  scale_fill_identity() +
  labs(caption = "Example shamelessly adapted from Claus Wilke") +
theme(
    axis.text.y = element_markdown(),
    plot.caption = element_markdown(lineheight = 1.2)
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I may even have overcomplicated it - I added the <b> tag because I thought the OP wanted to have the superscript bold too.

Comment: Thanks @Tjebo. Bold is in fact not necessary.