# Using subscript and italics in ggplot2 axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, histogram, axis-labels

I am using ggplot2 to create a histogram, but have been struggling to format the axis label. I have so far used to code below to insert a greek letter in the label, but would also like the 'K' to be in italics and the 'D' to be subscript so that the label looks like *K* <sub>D</sub> (µM)

`labs(x=expression(paste('KD (', mu, 'M)')))`

Comment: Do any of the following help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/17334759/3358272 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/27445452/3358272. (Searching SO and google in general can be hard for R, these two were found with [`[r] ggplot2 label subscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+ggplot2%20label%20subscript), fyi.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subscript letters in ggplot axis label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334759/subscript-letters-in-ggplot-axis-label)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to format without using the `expression` method is to use simple html.
I recommend the [`ggtext` package](https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/)

see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293715/how-to-use-greek-symbols-in-ggplot2/52322702#52322702) regarding Greek text in `ggplot2`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext) # 
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(drat), bins = 20) +
  labs(x="K<sub><i>D</i></sub>(\u00b5M)") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_markdown())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>