# How to type subscript/superscript in the category labels in bar plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to make subscript or superscript in the category labels (Fig.1) by ggplot2 in R. I found there are solutions for the axis text (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445452/superscript-and-subscript-axis-labels-in-ggplot2)), but not for the category labels.

For example, if the bar chart has 3 categories (K_a, K_b, K_c), then there will be 3 places to change the form (not one place which is the axis text).

[image: Fig.1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by passing `scales::parse_format` to the labels argument of the scale. Using `?plotmath` notation you have to recode your categories as e.g. `K[b]` to get a subscript "b":

```r
df <- data.frame(
  x = paste0("K[", letters[1:3], "]"),
  y = 1:3
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = scales::parse_format())
```

[image]